# How do you move a SharePoint 2010 DocumentSet from one list to another?

Tags: api, sharepoint-2010

I've tried many variations.

1. Send To Library - That creates a Zipped file in the Drop Off Library, then it doesn't route via the rules in Content Organizer
2. API - I've tried to do an Export, Import, but always receive the same error.  This is per this MSDN documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentsets.documentset.create.aspx

Sample snippet:

byte[] exportedFile = set.Export();

DocumentSet.Import(exportedFile, DocSetNameToCreate, targetFolder, dsCt.Id, properties, web.CurrentUser);

Error Received:

**DocID: Site prefix not set**.

Comment: This blog poster has the same issue, no solution yet:  http://www.sharepoint2010blog.nl/2010/07/20/Moving+A+DocumentSet+Through+Code+Pt1.aspx

Comment: I finally accomplished most of this by using the DocumentSet.Create command.  This comes with the DocumentManagement namespace which you need to add.  It was able to create a new DocumentSet, but I still have to programmatically copy over the metadata, as well as the files within that document library.  The .CopyTo method off of a SPListItem object worked great (copies both files and meta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to run.  This is related to the Document ID Feature.  Make sure it is activated in each site.  Let is run over night (timer jobs need to run).  Then the content organizer will successfully move and unpackage your document sets.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to activate the document id feature, just ensure that in the property bag of the root web of the destination site collection (where the document set will be imported again) exists a property named "docid_msft_hier_siteprefix" with an value of "" (empty string).

Use this powershell-script:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://host/sites/yoursite
$properties = $site.RootWeb.Properties

if ($properties["docid_msft_hier_siteprefix"] -eq $null)
{
    $properties["docid_msft_hier_siteprefix"] = ""
    $properties.Update()
}
```

Note that i use the old property bag RootWeb.Properties instead of the new hashtable RootWeb.AllProperties, thats because the class Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.Internal.OobProvider still uses that.

So why is it failing when a document set is imported? The function DocumentSet.ImportProperties() catches an ArgumentException while trying to set the document id of the document set list item (so there's no problem if the document id column doesn't exist yet).

But they missed that the function OobProvider.GetSitePrefix() which is called through the function OobProvider.GenerateDocumentId() throws an InvalidOperationException if the property bag doesn't contain the prefix property.

Comment: This solved my problems using DocumentSet.Import(). I don't have Document ID feature activated on my site collection.